# Dot products of three or more vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Can't we construct a mapping from $V^3(R^1)$ to $R$ such that $a.b.c = a_{x}b_{x}c_{x}+a_{y}b_{y}c_{y}+a_{z}b_{z}c_{z}$ (a,b,c are vectors in $V^3(R^1)$ ) and more generally $a^n$ , $a.b.c.d.e...$ mappings so that $(a^p)^{1/p}$ is the $p$ norm of vectors in $V^3$ ?

Comment: It would be nice to have a nice way to write products like these. Similarly to $a^Tb$ for `dual' inner products.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. To 'dot' together vectors $a$, $b$, $c$, make the diagonal matrix $B$ and write:

$a^T B c$

If you have more than three vectors to 'dot', just add more diagonal matrices in the middle.